# Ensure TestA is run before TestB

Tags: cmake

I have a setup like this:

```
ADD_TEST(NAME TestMyCode COMMAND MyCode myparams) #produces output.txt
ADD_TEST(CheckOutput CompareFiles output.txt baseline.txt)
```

It works exactly how I want when I run the tests sequentially, but if I use "ctest -jN", the order is (obviously) not preserved, so the data to compare is not necessarily available when the CheckOutput test is run. Is there any way to enforce an ordering? Saying "Run all the tests in parallel, but make sure A runs before B, and C runs before D, etc."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SET_TESTS_PROPERTIES(test2 PROPERTIES DEPENDS test1)
```

`test2` will run only after `test1` in this case.

Comment: Awesome, that sounds perfect. I will try it Monday and accept your answer once I see that it behaves as I need!